# Событие keydown в js странно себя ведет, почему?

Tags: javascript

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', fninput);
```

Когда я устанавливаю событие для input `keydown`, то оно срабатывает после второго нажатия на клавишу, приходится использовать событие `keyup`, но визуально `keyup` чуть медленнее работает, потому что срабатывает после отпускания кнопки.

Почему так происходит с событием `keydown` и какое есть решение?

Код:

```js
// создаю ссылки и задаю параметры
const input = document.querySelector('input[name=inputData]');
const outputData = document.querySelector('#noticeForUser');
const getInputClass = input.getAttribute('class');
input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Введите значение');
// объявляю функцию
const fninput = (handler) => {
  let output = Math.ceil(input.value / 0.97);
  if (input.value >= 1) {
    return outputData.innerHTML = output + ' руб.', input.removeAttribute('class'), input.setAttribute('class', getInputClass), outputData.removeAttribute('class');
  } else if (isNaN(input.value)) {
    return outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите цифры', input.setAttribute('class', 'bgred'), outputData.setAttribute('class', 'bgred');
  } else if (input.value === '') {
    return outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите значение', input.removeAttribute('class'), input.setAttribute('class', getInputClass), outputData.removeAttribute('class');
  } else if (input.value <= 0) {
    return outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите значение больше нуля', input.setAttribute('class', 'bgred'), outputData.setAttribute('class', 'bgred');
  } else {
    return outputData.innerHTML = '', input.removeAttribute('class'), input.setAttribute('class', getInputClass), outputData.removeAttribute('class');
  }
}
input.addEventListener('click', () => outputData.innerHTML = 'Введите значение');
input.addEventListener('keydown', fninput);
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <title>Store</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">ГЛАВНАЯ</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav class="header-nav bg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">МЕНЮ</div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="main" class="main bg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-self-center">
          <a id="link" href="/html/main.html">ссылка</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">2</div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <form name="myform">
            <span id="noticeForUser"></span>
            <br>
            <input class="brblack" type="text" name="inputData" autocomplete="off">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>













    <footer class="footer bg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          FOOTER
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abnf6uac/

Comment: в каком именно месте вы проставляете этот листенер?

Comment: при вводе в input

Comment: Добавьте полный код, который будет включать js  и html-разметку

Comment: Если вы добавляете при вводе в инпут, то при первом вводе у вас как раз и будет инициализироваться лисенер, который будет отрабатывать уже для 2+ нажатий

Comment: добавил код https://jsfiddle.net/abnf6uac/

Comment: и совсем не странно оно себя ведет, вы просто странно его использовали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что значение в поле ввода обновляется **после** события `keydown`.

Из-за этого проверка `input.value` - не дает результата, так как в value еще не добавлен нажатый символ.

---

Если в проверке нуждается не конкретный введенный символ, а полная строка можно воспользоваться, как [советует @Other](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828583/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-keydown-%D0%B2-js-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83/828611#comment1322882_828611), событием [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Comment: И, как следствие, юзаем `input` event ;)

Comment: я не знал, что есть input событие))) сколько не искал список событий для addEventListener, так и не смог найти. на англ. искать не могу, не знаю языка, а на русском мало инфы порой:(

Comment: короче, вопрос решил событием input. Сообществу в очередной раз спасибо за помощь:))

Comment: @Александр, события отличаются в зависимости от тега, поэтому лучше искать по нему

Comment: @Grundy, А разве в `input` нет свойства `data`, где последний символ?

Comment: @Other, не понял вопроса

Answer (score 0):

А у меня все работает:

```js
const log = document.getElementById('log');
const fninput = (e) => {
  log.innerHTML = "<br>" + e.code + log.innerHTML;
}

const input = document.getElementById("xmm");
input.addEventListener('keydown', fninput);
```

```html
<input id="xmm" type="text" />

<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: а что такое аргумент.code который вы написал в функции?

Comment: @Demon __ ANT https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code